# Retain rim around floor when drywalling? If not how to fill/insulate. . .

Tags: drywall, insulation, flooring, sound-proofing

Remodeling a vintage two-flat, tore down lath and plaster, now approaching drywall phase.

[The exterior walls have a wooden rim around perimeter of the floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjiWi.jpg)--what was this for?  I suppose it just set a boundary for the plaster and lath.

Should I rip this wooden rim out, or leave it?

When drywalling I'll be leaving the prescribed 1/2" gap between the bottom of the sheet and the floor.  I'm concerned about sound traveling between floors--with what should I seal this gap?

Comment: Yes, it's a screed board for the plaster and can be removed. Who prescribed a 1/2" gap? Drywall doesn't expand.

Comment: I've always seen gaps between the floor and the drywall

Comment: That's because 1) there's no reason to fit it perfectly, and 2) most walls are slightly over 8 feet high (or whatever 2x sheet height amounts to in your area). Doesn't mean the gap is required. There's an issue here because of the balloon framing. In newer construction there's a wall plate closing things off.